# Saving Nested Object with Hive in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am developing a bluetooth application and i want to save paired devices in device's local. I am using "flutter blue" package for bluetooth connection and i want to use "hive" for storing process. If i want to connect bluetooth device i have to use "flutter blue"s class.For example :

late BluetoothDevice device;        // device is an object of BluetoothDevice class

await device.connect();

This BluetoothDevice class has different arguments like id,name etc.

if i want to save the device and connect later, as you can see i have to store device as BluetoothDevice type.

I am trying to save the device with this extended hive class

```
part 'savedDevice.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)

class SavedDevice extends HiveObject {

  @HiveField(0)
  late BluetoothCharacteristic btcharacter;   //BluetoothCharacteristic is a flutter blue's class
  @HiveField(1)
  late BluetoothService btService;           //BluetoothService is a flutter blue's class
  @HiveField(2)
  late BluetoothDevice btdevice;             //BluetoothDevice is a flutter blue's class
  @HiveField(3)
  late String btid;

}
```

When i run it throws this error " Cannot write, unknown type: BluetoothCharacteristic. Did you forget to register an adapter? "

I think i have to register adapter for every classes that i use from "flutter blue"s classess.But i dont know how to do it. Could you help me with this ?

Btw i am facing only this problem at storing data. Other things works fine.

i generated above adapter class but it still shows the error